# Android: String resource is not working as desired

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a view have text with two different colors so I'm trying this code inside my `fragment`

```
TextView welcome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcome_text_ID);
View sample = getActivity().findViewById(R.string.sample);
welcome.setText("Welcome to " + sample);
```

and it says "Welcome to null"

Then I tried this

```
TextView welcome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcome_text_ID);
welcome.setText("Welcome to " + (R.string.sample));
```

and i get "Welcome to x1029203"

Which is the reference of the `int` of that `string` value found in the actual `R.java` file. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just setText(R.string.sample) then it is OK, but if you add something to it you need

```
welcome.setText("Welcome to " + getString(R.string.sample));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this:

```
welcome.setText("Welcome to " + getResources().getString((R.string.sample)));
```

A little excursus, why both `getResources().getString(Id)` and `getString()` work:

If you take a look at the [source code of `Fragment.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L783-L785), you'll see, that `getString()` calls `getResources().getString(Id)`, so both are the same:

```
 public final String getString(int resId) {
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`welcome_text_ID` can't be capitalized

Also, a string can't be an id to a view.

This is the correct code:

```
View sample = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sample);
```

Comment: why can't the id be capitalized?

Comment: it works fine with "ID" capitalized but you are right that it makes you set sample as a `View` not a `String`